# Why do we use arrays of middleware functions in express?

Tags: node.js, express

**can someone explain me why we are using this code in square brackets and why its assign to a** `const middlewares` , **Can we use it withou**t `const middlewares = [..]`

```
const middlewares = [
    layout(),
    express.static(path.join(__dirname,'views')),
    bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})
]
```

*Sorry for the inconvenience, i am new to this field*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code creates an array of 3 elements.

In this case an array of 3 function pointers.

We can't know exactly why the code you are looking at would have it but my guess is there is a system somewhere that wants to use this array so you create the array.

const is used to indicate that it won't be changed.

You should read about closure in node in order to understand more about how this works.

Answer (score 1):

The "square brackets" you mention are used to declare an [Array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals).

[`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) indicates that it's a constant and can't be changed once declared.

In this context (with your [express](/questions/tagged/express) tag), this array amalgamates several middlewares into a single structure to be applied at once, usually to a particular route. This is detailed in the official documentation on [Using Express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html):

> Middleware can also be declared in an array for reusability.
>
> This example shows an array with a middleware sub-stack that handles
> GET requests to the /user/:id path
>
> ```
> function logOriginalUrl (req, res, next) {
>    console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl)
>    next()
> }
>
> function logMethod (req, res, next) {
>    console.log('Request Type:', req.method)
>    next()
> }
>
> var logStuff = [logOriginalUrl, logMethod]
> app.get('/user/:id', logStuff, function (req, res, next) {
>     res.send('User Info')
> })
> ```